# ckan datapusher /api/3/action/resource_show (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused) error

Tags: python, datastore, ckan

I'm trying install ckan 2.2.1 + pgsql 9.1 + solr 3.6 + rhel 6.6.

I set file store, and datastore plugin. I tried to use 'upload to datastore' menu in ckan web. then I got this error.

```
2016-09-23 23:16:54,655 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /dataset/datastore/resource_data/7a82b5c2-d68c-4bed-b5c6-fcc460011455 render time 0.363 seconds
Job "push_to_datastore (trigger: RunTriggerNow, run = True, next run at: None)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/apscheduler/scheduler.py", line 512, in _run_job
    retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 300, in push_to_datastore
    resource = get_resource(resource_id, ckan_url, api_key)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/datapusher/datapusher/jobs.py", line 250, in get_resource
    'Authorization': api_key}
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 87, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 279, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 374, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 209, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='default.ckan.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/3/action/resource_show (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

ckan, solr is running well. datapusher with 8800 port is running.

```
$ curl localhost:8800
{
  "help": "\n        Get help at:\n        http://ckan-service-provider.readthedocs.org/."
}
```

Am I missing something for my datapusher ?
Thanks.

I added my ini

```
cache_dir = /tmp/%(ckan.site_id)s/
beaker.session.key = ckan
beaker.session.secret = CkL+a+Nc6grW1jBM/Ts69mRsE
app_instance_uuid = {f41a65ac-4a33-44fe-bb03-af15b456978e}
who.config_file = %(here)s/who.ini
who.log_level = warning
who.log_file = %(cache_dir)s/who_log.ini
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:PASS@localhost/ckan_default
ckan.datastore.write_url = postgresql://ckan_default:PASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.read_url = postgresql://datastore_default:PASS@localhost/datastore_default
ckan.datastore.default_fts_lang = english
ckan.datastore.default_fts_index_method = gist
ckan.site_url = http://ckan.daniel.com
ckan.auth.anon_create_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_unowned_dataset = false
ckan.auth.create_dataset_if_not_in_organization = false
ckan.auth.user_create_groups = false
ckan.auth.user_create_organizations = false
ckan.auth.user_delete_groups = true
ckan.auth.user_delete_organizations = true
ckan.auth.create_user_via_api = false
ckan.auth.create_user_via_web = true
ckan.auth.roles_that_cascade_to_sub_groups = admin
ckan.site_id = default
solr_url = http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan
ckan.plugins = stats text_view image_view recline_view datastore datapusher
ckan.views.default_views = image_view text_view recline_view
ckan.site_title = CKAN
ckan.site_logo = /base/images/ckan-logo.png
ckan.site_description =
ckan.favicon = /images/icons/ckan.ico
ckan.gravatar_default = identicon
ckan.preview.direct = png jpg gif csv
ckan.preview.loadable = html htm rdf+xml owl+xml xml n3 n-triples turtle plain atom csv tsv rss txt json
ckan.locale_default = en
ckan.locale_order = en pt_BR ja it cs_CZ ca es fr el sv sr sr@latin no sk fi ru de pl nl bg ko_KR hu sa sl lv
ckan.locales_offered =
ckan.locales_filtered_out = en_GB
ckan.feeds.authority_name =
ckan.feeds.date =
ckan.feeds.author_name =
ckan.feeds.author_link =
ckan.storage_path =  /usr/lib/ckan/korea/src/ckan/filestore
ckan.max_resource_size = 10
ckan.max_image_size = 5
ckan.datapusher.formats = csv xls xlsx tsv application/csv application/vnd.ms-excel application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
ckan.datapusher.url = http://ckan.daniel.com:8800/
ckan.hide_activity_from_users = %(ckan.site_id)s
```

Comment: Can you post your production.ini/development.ini? Looks like the ckan.site_url might be wrong.

Comment: I added my ini to above

Comment: I solve this problem by change port from 5000 to 80. and start ckan as root. But i have another problem. When I click "upload to datastore" I can see  "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ReadError'" error.

Comment: I think you need to go through the steps for production setup if you want this to all work well together. Debug/development setup on port 80 as root is not a great idea

Comment: I'm using redhat not ubuntu. Can i install ckan as a production on redhat? Can I do damonize ckan even if source installation?

Comment: The general approach is to set up the WSGI module for Apache amd have Apache handle the running of the Python source. See: http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed in your comment, the problem is that **the datapusher is trying to connect to the wrong port**:

> ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='default.ckan.com', **port=80**): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/3/action/resource_show (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)

You already found a possible workaround: changing CKAN's port to 80.

As an alternative workaround, I found that adding the port (the same one configured with `port` in the `[server:main]` section) to `ckan.site_url` makes the datapusher use it instead of the default HTTP port (80). So, in your case it could be:

```
ckan.site_url = http://default.ckan.com:5000
```

Of course, this is just another possible workaround; the *real* solution would be to fix the datapusher so that it correctly reads the port from the configuration ...